# $E S^1$ not homotopy equivalent to finite dimensionsl $S^1$-CW-Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to proof, that the universal $S^1$-bundle $ES^1$ is not homotopy equivalent, to a finite dimensional $S^1$-CW-Complex.

I think, I might assume, it is, so in $X_n=X$ at some step, and then showing, that $\pi_n(X) \neq 0$, because there is a free action of $S^1$, but I am stuck explaining why this holds, so any hints are highly welcome.

Comment: If it were, then $BS^1 = ES^1/S^1$ would be a finite dimensional CW-complex, but this has arbitrarily high degree nontrivial homology ($BS^1\simeq \mathbb CP^\infty$)

Comment: You might add what you mean by homotopy equivalent here. Do you mean homotopy equivalent through equivariant maps?